# $f(X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4+X_5|X_1,X_2,X_3) =$ ? (Conditional distribution of sum given subset of variables)

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, multivariate-normal-distribution

Dear StackExchange members,

I am wondering what the distribution of $f(X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4+X_5|X_1,X_2,X_3)$ is when the joint distribution of 
$(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4,X_5)$ 
is multivariate normal with mean 0 and covariance matrix $\Sigma$

I have a guess:

$f_{X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4+X_5}(t\mid X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2,X_3=x_3)=f_{X_4+X_5}(t-x_1-x_2-x_3\mid X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2,X_3=x_3)$.

My question is therefore: is this correct?

IF this is correct, I can derive the conditonal distribution myself:

Let $X_1+X_2+X_3=[1,1,1]\cdot[X_1,X_2,X_3]^T $. Then it is possible to derive the distribution of $f(X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4+X_5|X_1,X_2,X_3)$ using the conditioning rule of normal distributions. I can show the calculations below (after verifying that I am correct)

Comment: Marginally each of those is normal. The sum of normal rv is again normal with mean the sum of means and variance the variance of the sum, using the cov in the matrix to give you the covariance in the latter term. Then, you build the conditioning of this distribution.

Comment: $X_1+X_2+X_3$ given $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ is $X_1+X_2+X_3$. $(X_4,X_5)$ given $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ is $X_1+X_2+X_3$ is a Normal vector and $X_4+X_5=(1,1)(X_4,X_5)^\text{T}$, hence also Normal.